# Causes of sparseness in data

Tags: dataset

Can data sparseness appear due to either high sample size or high dimension? How different are the situations in the two cases? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am going to assume that by sparse you refer to data sets with many zeros and not to data sets which are of lower rank than the number of instances (e.g. redundant).

Neither large samples nor high dimensionality are *causes* for sparseness. You are likely to encounter sparseness more frequently in high dimensional problems, but this is certainly not a necessity.

Sparseness is a characteristic of the problem you are trying to solve and is often induced by the way raw data is vectorized. A typical example of highly sparse data is document classification when using the [bag-of-words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) representation of documents.